# Setting multiple headers in camel route

Tags: apache-camel

Is it possible to set multiple exchange headers in camel route using single call to setHeader.

Something like this

```
<from uri="file://inputdir/?delete=true" />
<!-- need to set multiple headers at once(as a comma separated list)-->
    <setHeader headerName="headername">
        <constant>headerval</constant>
    </setHeader>
<to uri="mock:end"/>
```

Or should I create a custom processor for this?

Comment: You can use multiple < setHeader > to set more than one header.

Comment: @ClausIbsen I am getting a dynamic list of headers(semicolon separated) in this route from an endpoint. Therefore I cannot know beforehand how many will be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cant set multiple headers at once as far as I am aware. In your case a custom processor  will probably be more effective.

You might want to look at the simple expression language here here is that you can OGNL notation in your camel route xml file. OGNL will allow  you to specify a chain of methods in the expression.

For example suppose you have a message that contains an `Employee` object that has a `getSalaryGrade()` method you could set a `header` to this value by using the following syntax:

```
<setHeader headerName="SalaryGrade">
    <simple>${body.getSalaryGrade()}</simple>
</setHeader>
```

You could for example create a simple class that returns a list and store the list in the header and then access the list via simple in the route. The following code is untested but should give you a idea.

```
public class ListCity {

    public List<String> ListCities()
    {
        ArrayList< String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("New York");
        list.add("JOhannesburg");   
        list.add("HoChiMinh");
        return list;
    }
 }
```

Declare the list city bean in your xml. You can then set this list into a header by using something like this:

```
<setHeader headerName="CityList">
    <simple>${listCity.ListCities()}</simple>
</setHeader>
```

Comment: Thanks Namphibian. I will create a custom processor for doing this.

Comment: @Arpit if the answer helps you please upvote it and if it is correct please mark it as correct.

Comment: Sure Namphibian, I would like to wait a little more in case someone has something we have not think of yet. Once again thanks for the answer.

Comment: @arpit perfectly fine with me. I hope I am wrong as this is a valid question.